# Tic Tac Toe - Draw and Win Bug after 9 moves

Tags: java, android

I have written a tic-tac-toe. However, its local multiplayer screen (I have one AI match screen too - completed) has 1 issue.

It detects win very easily until 9 boxes are played. If 9 boxes are played, it declares a draw even if any one has won.

Below is my code. Please help.

```
static int activePlayer = 0; //Handles the player state
static boolean gameIsActive = true; //Checks whether the game is active or not

static int gameMoves = 0; //Handles the number of game moves -- Useful in draw games (9 Moves)

static int[] gameState = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}; //Handles the GameState -- 2 means Unplayed

ImageView homeImageView; //Green Home Button
GridLayout boardGrid; //Tic-Tac-Toe Game Board
TextView resultTextView; //Dummy Result Text
Button resetButton; //Dummy Reset Button

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_local_multiplayer);


    //Initialization
    homeImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_green_home);
    boardGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.boardGrid);
    resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
    resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);

//Handles fading in animation of the board pieces + GAME LOGIC!
public void fadeIn(View view) {

    gameMoves++; //Increments the number of moves with each click on board piece

    //Getting the view into an boardPiece(ImageView) (ofcourse its an ImageView, thats why)
    ImageView boardPiece = (ImageView) view;

    //Game Logic

    int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(boardPiece.getTag().toString()); //Tapped Location
    int[][] winningPositions = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, {0, 3, 6},
            {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}}; //Winning Positions Location

    if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2 && gameIsActive) {

        gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;

        //Checking SharedPreferences Themes
        int themeChosen = Utils.loadPreferences(getBaseContext(), "theme", 0);

        //Changing Board Pieces based on Theme Selected
        if (themeChosen == 0) {
            if (activePlayer == 0) {
                boardPiece.setImageResource(R.drawable.nought);
                activePlayer = 1;
            } else if (activePlayer == 1) {
                boardPiece.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross);
                activePlayer = 0;
            }
            boardPiece.setTranslationY(-1000f); //Sets the view off-screen
            boardPiece.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(1000); //Gets it back on screen
        } else if (themeChosen == 1) {
            if (activePlayer == 0) {
                boardPiece.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
                activePlayer = 1;
            } else if (activePlayer == 1) {
                boardPiece.setImageResource(R.drawable.chocolate);
                activePlayer = 0;
            }
            boardPiece.setTranslationY(-1000f); //Sets the view off-screen
            boardPiece.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(1000); //Gets it back on screen
        } else if (themeChosen == 2) {
            if (activePlayer == 0) {
                boardPiece.setImageResource(R.drawable.tom);
                activePlayer = 1;
            } else if (activePlayer == 1) {
                boardPiece.setImageResource(R.drawable.jerry);
                activePlayer = 0;
            }
            boardPiece.setTranslationY(-1000f); //Sets the view off-screen
            boardPiece.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(1000); //Gets it back on screen
        } else if (themeChosen == 3) {
            if (activePlayer == 0) {
                boardPiece.setImageResource(R.drawable.wizard);
                activePlayer = 1;
            } else if (activePlayer == 1) {
                boardPiece.setImageResource(R.drawable.hog);
                activePlayer = 0;
            }
            boardPiece.setTranslationY(-1000f); //Sets the view off-screen
            boardPiece.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(1000); //Gets it back on screen
        } else if (themeChosen == 4) {
            if (activePlayer == 0) {
                boardPiece.setImageResource(R.drawable.bat);
                activePlayer = 1;
            } else if (activePlayer == 1) {
                boardPiece.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball);
                activePlayer = 0;
            }
            boardPiece.setTranslationY(-1000f); //Sets the view off-screen
            boardPiece.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(1000); //Gets it back on screen
        } else if (themeChosen == 5) {
            if (activePlayer == 0) {
                boardPiece.setImageResource(R.drawable.tiger);
                activePlayer = 1;
            } else if (activePlayer == 1) {
                boardPiece.setImageResource(R.drawable.mammoth);
                activePlayer = 0;
            }
            boardPiece.setTranslationY(-1000f); //Sets the view off-screen
            boardPiece.animate().translationYBy(1000f).setDuration(1000); //Gets it back on screen
        }
    }

    //Handles Winning - Losing
    for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions) {

        //Checking SharedPreferences Themes
        int themeChosen = Utils.loadPreferences(getBaseContext(), "theme", 0);

        if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]]
                && gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]]
                && gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {

            //Someone has won!
            gameIsActive = false; //Disable Game Playablity

            if (themeChosen == 0) {
                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0) {
                    //Noughts Won!
                    Log.i("winner", "normal1");
                    resultTextView.setText("Winner: Nought");
                } else {
                    //Cross Won!
                    Log.i("winner", "normal2");
                    resultTextView.setText("Winner: Cross");
                }
            } else if (themeChosen == 1) {
                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0) {
                    //Hearts Won!
                    Log.i("winner", "love1");
                    resultTextView.setText("Winner: Heart");
                } else {
                    //Chocolates Won!
                    Log.i("winner", "love2");
                    resultTextView.setText("Winner: Chocolate");
                }
            } else if (themeChosen == 2) {
                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0) {
                    //Tom Won!
                    Log.i("winner", "tomandjerry1");
                    resultTextView.setText("Winner: Tom");
                } else {
                    //Jerry Won!
                    Log.i("winner", "tomandjerry2");
                    resultTextView.setText("Winner: Jerry");
                }
            } else if (themeChosen == 3) {
                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0) {
                    //Wizards Won!
                    Log.i("winner", "clashofclans1");
                    resultTextView.setText("Winner: Wizard");
                } else {
                    //Hogs Won!
                    Log.i("winner", "clashofclans2");
                    resultTextView.setText("Winner: Hog");
                }
            } else if (themeChosen == 4) {
                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0) {
                    //Bat Won!
                    Log.i("winner", "cricket1");
                    resultTextView.setText("Winner: Bat");
                } else {
                    //Ball Won!
                    Log.i("winner", "cricket2");
                    resultTextView.setText("Winner: Ball");
                }
            } else if (themeChosen == 5) {
                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0) {
                    //Tiger Won!
                    Log.i("winner", "iceage1");
                    resultTextView.setText("Winner: Tiger");
                } else {
                    //Mammoth Won!
                    Log.i("winner", "iceage2");
                    resultTextView.setText("Winner: Mammmoth");
                }
            }
        } else if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2
                && gameState[winningPosition[0]] != gameState[winningPosition[1]]
                && gameState[winningPosition[1]] != gameState[winningPosition[2]]
                && gameMoves >= 9) {

            gameIsActive = false; //Disable Game Playablity

            //Its a draw!
            if (themeChosen == 0) {
                Log.i("winner", "normal");
                resultTextView.setText("Winner: Draw 1");
            } else if(themeChosen == 1) {
                Log.i("winner", "love");
                resultTextView.setText("Winner: Draw 2");
            } else if(themeChosen == 2) {
                Log.i("winner", "tomandjerry");
                resultTextView.setText("Winner: Draw 3");
            } else if(themeChosen == 3) {
                Log.i("winner", "clashofclans");
                resultTextView.setText("Winner: Draw 4");
            } else if(themeChosen == 4) {
                Log.i("winner", "cricket");
                resultTextView.setText("Winner: Draw 5");
            } else if(themeChosen == 5) {
                Log.i("winner", "iceage");
                resultTextView.setText("Winner: Draw 6");
            }
        }
    }

}

//Resetting game - Method
public void resetGame() {

    //Resets the Result Text
    resultTextView.setText("");

    //Resets the Game
    activePlayer = 0; //Clears the player state
    gameIsActive = true; //Reactivates the game - Sets it to activated state

    gameMoves = 0; //Resets the number of game moves done to 0

    //Clears the Game State
    gameState[0] = 2;
    gameState[1] = 2;
    gameState[2] = 2;
    gameState[3] = 2;
    gameState[4] = 2;
    gameState[5] = 2;
    gameState[6] = 2;
    gameState[7] = 2;
    gameState[8] = 2;

    //Clears the ImageViews
    for(int i = 0; i < boardGrid.getChildCount(); i++){
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) boardGrid.getChildAt(i);
        iv.setImageResource(0);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you narrow the code down to the part that determines who wins or loses? It's really hard to go through all this code, most of which is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: oops! wait let me do it ;)

Comment: there you go! only important stuff related ones left now....

Comment: `"A strange game... The only winning move is not to play."` (Cit.: W.O.P.R., from "WarGames")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue is that when it is looping through the different possible winning positions, if it encounters a possible winning position that is not 3 in a row, it will report it as a tie once 9 moves have been played. What you need to do is create an `int winner` and default that to `2`. Your `for` should look like this now

```
int winner = 2;
for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions) {

    //Checking SharedPreferences Themes
    int themeChosen = Utils.loadPreferences(getBaseContext(), "theme", 0);

    if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]]
            && gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]]
            && gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {

        //Someone has won!
        gameIsActive = false; //Disable Game Playablity

        winner = gameState[winningPosition[0]];
        break;
    } else if(gameMoves >= 9) {
        gameIsActive = false;
    }
}
```

Then outside the for loop you should have

```
if(winner != 2) {
  CODE FOR HANDLING WIN HERE
} else {
  CODE FOR HANDLING DRAW HERE
}
```

Comment: man! its calling the Draw handling part just after one move :"(

Comment: damn, so stupid...just added if(gameMoves == 9) and got it fixed...thanx a lot man...you got my headache fixed :)

Comment: No worries. When you're working with complex/large looping structures, it's really hard to see if you have a slight error in logic. A second pair of eyes is always useful.

Comment: thanx for your witty words. :)

Comment: man, however there's one issue.... as i have moved the winning logic into a specific code block ... it cant access the winningPosition value - like gameState[winningPosition[0]] --- shows error ..... because it isnt accessible in that code block. I tried passing global variable for the foreach loop but doesnt works.. any suggestions :\

Comment: Create a variable `int[] position` and set it equal to the winning position within the `if` block.

Comment: damn....feeling stupid ..... right! it all works now! Thanx for all your help.... wont forget ;)